# Problem: mouse/touchpad work under live environment but do not function once OS is installed

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, lubuntu, mouse, touchpad

I've run into a very frustrating problem when trying to install xubuntu and lubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.  While running the liveCD both my USB mouse and the touchpad work perfectly, but once the OS is installed and I reboot, everything goes to hell in a handbasket.  Namely:

1. Mouse and touchpad no longer work (also tried rebooting/reinstalling without the USB mouse)
2. `ctrl + F2` doesn't drop to a terminal.   It just gives me a black screen.
3. This is NOT an ASUS (or was it Acer?) notebook and I'm fairly confident that my problem is unrelated to that one (as evidenced by the fact that I get **no** mouse movement at all).

**What can I do to diagnose and fix this problem?**

Additional information:

This may or may not be relevant but I've noticed that upon rebooting after a successful installation, the screen resolution drops to below native.  Perhaps there's a video driver issue, but I fail to see how the two things could be related.